# http or https for registering on an iPhone push notification server?

Tags: iphone, push-notification, appstore-approval

I am implementing a push notification service in an iPhone app and I let the app register on a push notification server eat startup, sending the device token via http.

I would like to know if it is okay to send that data via http or do I have to use https? I know its not secure to send by http but can using http be a reason to reject my iPhone from the appStore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i send mine via http - no probs